# Excel VBA - Copy data from multiple sheets into a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I'd like to be able to copy data from multiple sheets into a table without deleting the table's formatting.

- The data being copied from each sheet will always contain 6 columns
- But the number of rows in each sheet will vary.
- Additionally, I do not want the first two rows of each sheet to be copied.
- I'd like the data from all of the copied sheets to be pasted one after another into a single preexisting table starting at B2, without deleting the table's formatting.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to achieve with a macro as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Sub copyrange()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim DestRng As Range, r As Long
    For r = 2 To 7
        Set DestRng = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        Sheets(r).Range("A3:F" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Alternatively:

```
Sub copyrange2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim DestRng As Range, r As Long
    Dim DestSht As Worksheet: Set DestSht = Sheet1
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet: Set sht1 = Sheets("2ndSheet")
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet: Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Dim sht3 As Worksheet: Set sht3 = Sheets("Sheet4")
    Dim sht4 As Worksheet: Set sht4 = Sheets("Sheet5")
    Dim sht5 As Worksheet: Set sht5 = Sheets("Sheet6")
    Dim sht6 As Worksheet: Set sht6 = Sheets("Sheet7")
    Dim shts
    shts = Array(Sheets("2ndSheet"), Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5, Sheet6, Sheet7)
    For r = 0 To 5
        Set DestRng = DestSht.Range("A" & DestSht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        shts(r).Range("A3:F" & shts(r).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You could also keep the tables you are accessing on a seperate workbook and query them using a dataquery.

HTH
Justin